# How to remove gnome terminal profiles in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, gnome-terminal

I can't seem to find a way to remove a broken gnome terminal profile I've setup from the list under File -> Open Terminal.

How does one remove one of these from the list?  I can't change the settings because it opens and closes so fast.  GNOME Terminal 3.18.3.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `dconf-editor` in order to edit/remove terminal profile if you cannot access `gnome-terminal` menu.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open `dconf-editor` then navigate to `org > gnome > terminal > legacy > profiles`. From there you can modify the profile.

[image]

<sub>Screenshot taken at 14.04 with `gconf-editor`</sub>

Comment: I'm using 16.04, and there's nothing there...

Answer (score 1):

Execute `gnome-terminal -- bash` or `gnome-terminal -- zsh` (whichever is not a misconfigured shell) or `gnome-terminal -- /bin/sleep 1000` or something similar to open gnome-terminal in case by default it closes way too quickly due to a broken startup command. Then you can open the Edit -> Preferences or Profile Preferences dialog and fix the problem.

Beginning with gnome-terminal 3.22 (Ubuntu Artful) you can even use the command `gnome-terminal --preferences` to open the Preferences window directly.